# Facebook Graph API throws error when posting to /comments endpoint on ratings open graph story

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to create a comment on the open graph story that is generated when a user leaves a rating for a Facebook page.

The posted comment is successfully created on Facebook, but the API consistently returns an error response.

```
"error": {
    "message": "Unsupported request - method type: post",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "APR_H1BL2qZEqz8glU-XZSJ"
  }
}
```

In addition I'm receiving an empty array when trying to view the comments for the open graph story, despite it having several comments. When I query comments for regular posts (not ratings) on the page, these return as expected.

I'm making these requests using an access token that has full permission to manage this page and has these granted permissions:

```
pages_show_list
pages_read_engagement
pages_manage_metadata
pages_read_user_content
pages_manage_posts
pages_manage_engagement
```

The app is live, verified, and has been granted advanced access to `pages_manage_engagement`.

Comment: what is your url ?